# Significance, or lack thereof of capital $N$ in Maxwell's distribution of molecular speeds

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I recently came across two versions of Maxwells equation that gives the distribution of molecular speeds:

$$n\left(v\right)dv\:=\:4\pi N\left(\frac{m}{2\pi kT}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}v^2e^{-\frac{mv^2}{2kT}}dv$$

The other form did not have the capital $N$ in it.

My question is what are the usage cases of the two different equations and what is the physical meaning of each?

Comment: "The other form" -- what other form? I would guess that $N$ is the total number of particles, and this formula you've written is for the number density of particles with velocity $v$ to $v+dv$, while the "other form" is the probability density for particles with velocity $v$ to $v+dv$. But it is impossible to say for sure unless you define all the terms in your equation and show explicitly what equations you are comparing.

Comment: With $N$ the formula gives the *number* of molecules with velocity $v$ out of a population of $N$ particles. Without the $N$ it gives the *fraction* of the population with velocity $v$.

Answer (score 0):

When $N$ is not showing in equation, that is giving expectation value,$$\left<x\right>=\frac{\sum_i=n_ix_i}{\sum_in_i=N}$$And when $N$ is showing as multiple, then that is giving total value,$$X=N\left<x\right>=\sum_in_ix_i$$